# Web service which allows chat with mathematics formulas

Tags: webapp-rec

The [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/charttools/index.html) supports creating good looking formulas based upon LaTeX input:

[image: formula example]

Does someone know an online chat service which makes use of that API to display discussed formulas, maybe with the use of editor such as seen in [Knol](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-docs-has-equation-editor.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a shared Google Document, put equations in the document (via Insert->Equation) and use the chat window that is available in all Docs applications. It won't allow the equations to appear inline with the chat, but at least you'd be able to see them and discuss...

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [**MathIM**](http://www.mathim.com/), which is an online chat room which parses everything between `$$`'s in your message as TeX.  It's perfect for talking to my friends when I need to use math equations.

It seems to be exactly what you are looking for :)

Comment: yeah, looks really good. can i host this myself?

Comment: I don't believe that there is an API that allows you to host this on your own server, but you can create (relatively) private rooms that are infinitely reusable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Pidgin (http://www.pidgin.im/) is an IM client for windows, MacOS and Linux. Then install this pidgin plugin: [pidgintext](http://code.google.com/p/pidgintex/)

Comment: yep, i know this one. the problem is to explain other users how to install that stuff. so, a web based solution is prefered.

Answer (score 0):

[GmailChatTeX](http://alexeev.org/gchattex.html) may work for you.